# BLE Module CSR1010 disconnection Issues

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been using CSR1010 Module to trigger a test of the luminary. I Am getting connected to the BLE module using the Android App by the name BLE-Scanner. 
Using this app I am able to get connected to the device for all the time possible. But when I trigger the test in the device, after sometime the application gets disconnected from the device .

Any solutions to keep the Bluetooth connection intact when test is executing for some standard time interval like 30 or 60 min?

Comment: Please show your code. Without that noboby could help you.

Comment: @Mike which code you want me to share ? My project has many modules. like there are some ten " .c " extension files . Do you know which module I should be posting here ? Also do u have any idea as to which parameter I should be taking care off which is now resulting in disconnection ?